# Find the derivative $y=({1\over x})^x$

Tags: implicit-differentiation

I got $y'= x^2 + \ln({1\over x})\times ({1\over x})^x$

Am I correct?

So $y'=-x^{-x}(\ln{x} + 1)$

Comment: Hint: Take log on both sides.

Comment: You can check your work here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+1%2Fx%5Ex

Comment: why can't i use the natural log?

Comment: @ data: You $should$ use natural log.

Answer (score 2):

$$y = x^{-x} \implies \log(y) = -x \log(x)$$ Can you now do implicit differentiation?

Comment: I used ln instead of log.

Comment: Well, log is more widely used, but this unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

Some logarithms and the chain rule:

$$y=\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e^{\frac{1}{x}\log x}\Longrightarrow y'=e^{\frac{1}{x}\log x}\left[-\frac{1}{x^2}\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}\right]=$$

$$=\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\left(1-\log x\right)=\frac{1}{x^{x+2}}(1-\log x)$$